# Call SOAP web services from a play framework (2.2.4) application

Tags: java, web-services, soap-client, playframework-2.2

I am working on a web application developed using Play framework **2.2.4**(Java) and now I need to call some SOAP web services from within my web application.

---

I am new to Play framework and web services and I am confused on how to do it.

So far I have only managed to used the WSDL for the SOAP services to generate the java classes using `wsimport`.

I came across the `WS` API of the play framework to asynchronously call the web services and I have the following doubts.

1. How can I call these SOAP services using the `WS` API of the play framework?
2. In play framework, is it necessary to use this `WS` API to make a web service client, or can it be done using other ways?

It would be really helpful if someone can share a small tutorial to do this.

Comment: did you found any solution ?